# How to pass ejs data to javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, ejs

Is there a clean way to pass the data back from `ejs` to a javascript variable via something like an on click event? I know I could get away traversing the DOM with some `parentElement`, `children` shenanigans to get the data from `innerHTML` or something but it seems kind of messy and I hope there's a better way. What I really need is to get the `product._id` to save it to the shopping cart but I really don't like the idea of having an invisible div with `<%- product._id %>` inside it in order to get it.

```
            <div class="productSection">
              <% products.forEach(function(product){ %>                         
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-title"><%- product.name %></div>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-body-price"><%- product.price %></div>
                      </div>
                      <button class="card-cartBtn">+</button>
                    </div>              
              <% }) %>
            </div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `data-` attributes?

Comment: Why not place the `product.id` inside of a function that lives on your button?

Answer (score 0):

As Chayim Friedman suggested, using `data-` attributes is a perfect solution. I didn't know it existed.

`<div class="productSection-minCard" data-id="<%= product._id %>">`